# How to enable and disable usb debugging option through adb wifi in shell script

Tags: android

Want to check usb connection /disconnection with the android phone to my devkit,so want to automate this scenario without manual connect and disconnects.

I ran the adb usb command in pc (pc and phone connected through wifi adb) then usb disconnection and connecion message observed,After that adb devices command not showing device list/adb usb command is also not working.

Could you please help me to automate this task.

Comment: check this links. Hope it helps you. http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/120394/can-i-enable-usb-debugging-using-adb

Comment: This wont work in my case.